# Round Product Price In magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-prices, rounding

I want to modification in the product price. For example, if the product has priced $13.45 then it should display $13 but the price is more than $13.50 it should be $14.

So how to modify product price?

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/lillik-module-price-decimal.html - try with this module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to override `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` using `di.xml`

Path of `di.xml`: `Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
    <plugin name="productpricechange" type=" Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
</config>
```

Now create a plugin file path should be: `Vendor/Module/Plugin/Product.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

    class Product
    {
        public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
        {
            return round($result);
        }
    }
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: It's working. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear, it help you. please mark my answer correct so it helps other readers as well

Answer (score 1):

> **[round](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) Function**

```
<?php
$price = 13.45;
echo(round($price)); //output 13

$price_change = 13.50;
echo(round($price_change)); //output 13
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create **di.xml** for create plugin :

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> 
<type name="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency">
    <plugin name="vendor_module" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Currency" />
</type>
```

Now, create plugin file

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Plugin/Currency.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;

class Currency
{
    public function aroundConvert($subject, $proceed, $price, $toCurrency = null)
    {
        $price = $proceed($price, $toCurrency);
        // Your logic
        return $price; // It will be affect in price of shipping also.
    }
}
```

It will be rounding price with Multi-Currency Stores.

For reference : [click here](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.Price)